# import obj file (from turbosquid) only diffuse material, no textures

Tags: cycles-render-engine, import

I have downloaded couple of free 3D models from turbosquid but I'm unable to see them fully textured after I imported them as obj. files.

Materials are loaded with diffuse shader only, however I can see texture files(jpgs) in UV/image editor

Link to a model: http://www.turbosquid.com/FullPreview/Index.cfm/ID/834553

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you[image]
[image]

Comment: Switch top blender internal ([see this image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0cVN3.png)). The obj importer does not create the materials for cycles. For cycles you need to recreate the materials manually, if they use images as textures you need to create the nodes for it.

Comment: Obj file format doesn't include complex material definitions, only basic textures are maintained when imported. You have to create materials yourself for the render you are currently using (Cycles). Also have in mind that Blender viewport has limited material preview support, especially for Cycles